# Initiate download pop up from node.js API /response/

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, http

I have this file download API

```
    itemsRouter.route('/download/:id/:category/:type/:price/:name')
    .get(function(req,res){
        var currentDownloadIndex=0;
        if(req.session.username){
            // var uri = url.parse(req.url).id;
            var filename = path.join(process.cwd(),'/uploads/files/'+ req.params.category+'/'+req.params.id+'.'+req.params.type);
            path.exists(filename, function(exists) {
                if(!exists) {

                    //file doesn't exist
                    res.redirect('/');
                } else {
                    //if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory())
                    //    filename += '/Justin Bieber - What Do You Mean.mp4';
                 try {
                    var stat = fs.statSync(filename);
                    res.writeHeader(200,{"Content-Length":stat.size});
                    var fReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
                    fReadStream.pipe(res);       
                    if(!(req.session.items[req.params.name]==req.params.name)){
                    req.session.price=parseFloat(req.session.price)+parseFloat(req.params.price);
                    req.session.items[req.params.name]=req.params.name;
                    currentDownloadIndex=currentDownloadIndex+1

                    }

                    // Todo : Generate a report after each success full download 
                    }
                     catch (error) {
                     if(currentDownloadIndex==1){
                    req.session.price=parseFloat(req.session.price)-parseFloat(req.params.price);
                    req.session.items[req.session.items.length]=(req.params.name);

                     }   

                    }

                }
            });
        }else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }

    });
```

This works fine for video file just downloads the file on the browser however when pdf file is downloaded it opens in the browser and am not comfortable with that,Can anybody show me how to initiate the download with out any mess
thanks

Comment: provide content-type header of your file type.

Comment: just finished testing that and it again loading it on the browser  but with error this time.

Answer (score 1):

Add content-type header as "application/pdf".